# Oracle sql query needs to optimize

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following requirements.

I want to fetch the job schedules of the staffs for particular day(current day) and particular store (e.g. 12). Also, there is scenario that other store (13) staffs will come and work for store (12) and store 12 staffs can work for other stores.

Status table is storing the present/Absent details if staffs mark their attendance.

I want to fetch 
1) the schedules of the staffs for the store 12 from staffschedules regardless of staffstatus  has entry or not on the particular day.

2) the schedules from staffschedules who are all from other stores and reject the schedules of the staffs who went to other stores by referring the staffstatus (if entry is in status table, i need to retrieve, else nothing)

2 Tables:

1. Schedules
2. Status ----> staffs present/absent details

I have written the below query. It takes average of 30 seconds to run. In worst cases, 93 seconds.

```
STAFFSCHEUDLES TABLE SCHEMA: 

CREATE TABLE "STAFFSCHEDULES"
 (
"STORE_ID" VARCHAR2(75 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"START_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE,
"JOB_ID"             VARCHAR2(22 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"START_TIME"   VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,   
"END_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE,
"END_TIME" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"JOBNAME"       VARCHAR2(1500 BYTE)  
CONSTRAINT "PK_STAFFSCHEDULES" PRIMARY KEY ("STORE_ID", "START_DATE", "JOB_ID", "START_TIME") 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_STAFFSCHEDULES" ON "STAFFSCHEDULES"
 (
"STORE_ID", "START_DATE", "JOB_ID", "START_TIME"
 )

CREATE INDEX "IDX1_STAFFSCHEDULES_STORSTDT" ON "STAFFSCHEDULES"
 (
  "STORE_ID",
  "START_DATE"
   )

CREATE INDEX "STAFFSCHEDULES_IDX" ON "STAFFSCHEDULES"
  (
  "JOB_ID"
  )   


STAFFSTATUS TABLE SCHEMA: 


CREATE TABLE "STAFFSTATUS"
 (
"JOB_SEQ_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"JOB_ID"      VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"STORE_ID"    VARCHAR2(4 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"JOB_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE,
"STATUS"      VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'N'  ,
"SERVER_DATE"   DATE  
CONSTRAINT "PK_STAFFSTATUS" PRIMARY KEY ("JOB_SEQ_ID") 
CONSTRAINT "UK_STAFFSTATUS" UNIQUE ("JOB_ID", "STORE_ID", "JOB_DATE") 
 )

CREATE INDEX "INDEX_STAFFSTATUS" ON "STAFFSTATUS"
 (
"STORE_ID",
"STATUS"
  )

CREATE INDEX "INDEX_STAFFSTATUS_JOB_DT" ON "STAFFSTATUS"
(
"STORE_ID",
"JOB_DATE",
"STATUS"
 )

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_STAFFSTATUS" ON "STAFFSTATUS"
 (
"JOB_SEQ_ID"
 )

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "UK_STAFFSTATUS" ON "STAFFSTATUS"
 (
"JOB_ID", "STORE_ID", "JOB_DATE"
 )

 CREATE INDEX "INDEX_STAFFSTATUS_UPDT" ON "STAFFSTATUS"
   (
    "STORE_ID",
  "SERVER_DATE"
    )
```

QUERY TO RETRIEVE THE SCHEDULES:

```
           SELECT *                      
              From StaffSchedules  
              WHERE store_id='15'                 
              AND ((start_date BETWEEN TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')) AND TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))+(1-1/24/60/60)
                  AND TO_CHAR(start_date,'HH24:MI') <= start_time)
                  OR((end_date BETWEEN TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))+1/24/60/60 AND TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))+1)
                  AND TO_CHAR(end_date,'HH24:MI') >= end_time))

              AND job_id NOT IN
               (SELECT distinct s2.job_id
                FROM staffschedules s2 
                WHERE s2.store_id=store_id                  
                AND ((s2.start_date BETWEEN TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')) AND TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))+(1-1/24/60/60)
                   AND TO_CHAR(s2.start_date,'HH24:MI') <= s2.start_time)
                   OR((s2.end_date BETWEEN TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))+1/24/60/60 AND TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))+1)
                   AND TO_CHAR(s2.end_date,'HH24:MI') >= s2.end_time))
                AND SUBSTR(ses2.org_path,INSTR(ses2.org_path,'/',1,7)+1,8) = 'NOTALLOCATED') 

              AND job_id NOT IN (

                       Select job_Id From staffStatus Where Trunc(job_Date)=Trunc(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')) And Store_Id!='15')           


       UNION ALL

               SELECT *                       
                    From StaffSchedules ss
                    Right Outer Join staffStatus status On Es.job_Id=status.job_Id And status.Store_Id<>ss.Store_Id And 
                      (Trunc(status.job_Date)=Trunc(ss.Start_Date) Or Trunc(status.job_Date)=Trunc(ss.End_Date)) 

                    AND ((start_date BETWEEN TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')) AND TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))+(1-1/24/60/60)
                  AND TO_CHAR(start_date,'HH24:MI') <= start_time)
                  OR((end_date BETWEEN TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))+1/24/60/60 AND TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))+1)
                  AND TO_CHAR(end_date,'HH24:MI') >= end_time))

                AND job_id NOT IN
                 (SELECT distinct s2.job_id
                  FROM staffschedules s2 
                  WHERE s2.store_id=store_id                  
                  AND ((s2.start_date BETWEEN TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')) AND TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))+(1-1/24/60/60)
                    AND TO_CHAR(s2.start_date,'HH24:MI') <= s2.start_time)
                    OR((s2.end_date BETWEEN TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))+1/24/60/60 AND TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))+1)
                   AND TO_CHAR(s2.end_date,'HH24:MI') >= s2.end_time))
                 AND SUBSTR(ses2.org_path,INSTR(ses2.org_path,'/',1,7)+1,8) = 'NOTALLOCATED') 


              AND  status.store_id='15' AND TRUNC(status.job_date)=TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))            
              ORDER BY job_id,start_date,start_time;
```

EXECUTION PLAN:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name                           | Rows  | Bytes | Cost    (%CPU)| Time     |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   -------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |                                |    41 | 10865 |      37990   (1)| 00:07:36 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                  |                                |    41 | 10865 | 37989  (67)| 00:07:36 |
|   2 |   UNION-ALL                     |                                |       |          |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS ANTI            |                                |     1 |   265 | 12649   (1)| 00:02:32 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS ANTI           |                                |     1 |   146 | 12620   (1)| 00:02:32 |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| STAFFSCHEDULES                 |   109 | 13734 | 12401   (1)| 00:02:29 |
|*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX1_STAFFSCHEDULES_STORSTDT   | 65068 |       |   410   (1)| 00:00:05 |
|*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN           | UK_STAFFSTATUS                 |   137K|  2694K|     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | STAFFSCHEDULES                 |     1 |   119 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN           | STAFFSCHEDULES_IDX             |    83 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |    NESTED LOOPS ANTI            |                                |    40 | 10600 | 25340   (1)| 00:05:05 |
|  11 |     NESTED LOOPS                |                                |    40 |  5840 | 24820   (1)| 00:04:58 |
|  12 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| STAFFSTATUS                    |  2208 | 44160 |  2931   (1)| 00:00:36 |
|* 13 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN          | INDEX_STAFFSTATUS_SCHD_DT      |  2208 |       |  1525   (1)| 00:00:19 |
|* 14 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| STAFFSCHEDULES                 |     1 |   126 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN          | STAFFSCHEDULES_IDX             |    83 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | STAFFSCHEDULES                 |     1 |   119 |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 17 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN           | PK_STAFFSCHEDULES              |     1 |       |    12   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - filter(("START_DATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-08 23:59:59', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
          "START_DATE">=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-08 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
          "START_TIME">=TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION(START_DATE"),'HH24:MI') OR 
          "END_DATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-09 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
          "END_DATE">=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-08 00:00:01', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
          "END_TIME"<=TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("END_DATE"),'HH24:MI')))

   6 - access("STORE_ID"='15')
   7 - access("JOB_ID"="JOB_ID")
       filter(TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("JOB_DATE"))=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-08 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd 
          hh24:mi:ss') AND "STORE_ID"<>'15')
   8 - filter("S2"."STORE_ID"='15' AND ("S2"."START_DATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-08 23:59:59', 
          'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "S2"."START_DATE">=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-08 00:00:00',     'syyyy-mm-dd 
          hh24:mi:ss') AND "S2"."START_TIME">=TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("S2"."START_DATE"),'HH24:MI'
          ) OR "S2"."END_DATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-09 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
          "S2"."END_DATE">=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-08 00:00:01', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
          "S2"."END_TIME"<=TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("S2"."END_DATE"),'HH24:MI')) AND 
          SUBSTR("S2"."JOBNAME",INSTR("S2"."JOBNAME",'/',1,7)+1,8)='NOTALLOCATED')
   9 - access("JOB_ID"="S2"."JOB_ID")
  13 - access("STATUS"."STORE_ID"='15')
   filter(TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("STATUS"."JOB_DATE"))=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-08 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd 
          hh24:mi:ss'))
  14 - filter(("START_DATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-08 23:59:59', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
          "START_DATE">=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-08 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
          "START_TIME">=TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("START_DATE"),'HH24:MI') OR 
          "END_DATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-09 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
          "END_DATE">=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-08 00:00:01', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
          "END_TIME"<=TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("END_DATE"),'HH24:MI')) AND 
          "STATUS"."STORE_ID"<>"STORE_ID" AND (TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("STATUS"."JOB_DATE"))=TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCT
          ION("START_DATE")) OR TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("STATUS"."JOB_DATE"))=TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("
          END_DATE"))) AND "STORE_ID"<>'15')
  15 - access("STATUS"."JOB_ID"="JOB_ID")
  16 - filter(("S2"."STORE_ID"='15' AND ("S2"."START_DATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-08 23:59:59', 
          'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "S2"."START_DATE">=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-08 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd 
          hh24:mi:ss') AND "S2"."START_TIME">=TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("S2"."START_DATE"),'HH24:MI'
          ) OR "S2"."END_DATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-09 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
          "S2"."END_DATE">=TO_DATE(' 2013-07-08 00:00:01', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
          "S2"."END_TIME"<=TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("S2"."END_DATE"),'HH24:MI')) AND 
          SUBSTR("S2"."JOBNAME",INSTR("S2"."JOBNAME",'/',1,7)+1,8)='NOTALLOCATED')
  17 - access("S2"."STORE_ID"="STORE_ID" AND "JOB_ID"="S2"."JOB_ID")
      filter("JOB_ID"="S2"."JOB_ID" AND "S2"."STORE_ID"<>'15')
```

Sample Staffschedule data:

```
storeid  job_id       startdate          starttime           enddate          endtime   jobname
 12         1     2013-07-11 09:00:00     09:00         2013-07-11 18:00:00     10:00     class A
 12         1     2013-07-11 09:00:00     10:00         2013-07-11 18:00:00     11:00     class B
 12         1     2013-07-11 09:00:00     11:00         2013-07-11 18:00:00     18:00     class C
```

Please help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the table structures of the two tables? Why do you need to `store` in both the tables? Will staff that are originally in `store 12` also be present in staffstatus?

Comment: Please show the explain plan output, and what indexes exist, etc.  We are not mind readers.

Comment: Explain plan is updated. Please have a look and share your points.

Comment: There are a lot of predicates here, it's difficult to tell where the plan is going wrong.  Can you simplify the query to pinpoint which predicate is causing issues?  You may want to look into using [gather_plan_statistics or SQL monitoring](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/how_do_i_know_if) to find if there's one particular step with a really bad cardinality.  The optimizer may be under-estimating the cardinality, using indexes when a full table scan would work better.  [Expression statitics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/stats.htm#BEICJCJH) may help here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are big changes in question data, so let's examine it from scratch.

First of all, in query text present one unspecified thing:

```
AND SUBSTR(ses2.org_path,INSTR(ses2.org_path,'/',1,7)+1,8) = 'NOTALLOCATED')
```

There are no table with alias `ses2` in query, so I have no ideas about what to do with that thing. Only note that it never evaluates to `true` because `length('NOTALLOCATED')` more than 8. So that condition removed from answer.

The main factor affecting query performance is overuse of `NOT IN` conditions. Such conditions in most cases must be changed to simple tests against field in main query.
In query from question we have situation like that:

```
select 
  t.*
from
  my_table t
where 
  <big-basket-of-conditions-here>
  and
  t.field_1 not in ( select t.field_1 
                     from my_table t
                     where 
                       <same-big-basket-of-conditions>     
                       and
                       <one_more_test>
                   )
```

which must be changed to

```
select 
  t.*
from
  my_table t
where 
  <big-basket-of-conditions-here>
  and
  not (<one-more-test>)
```

E.g. you have:

```
          AND job_id NOT IN
           (SELECT distinct s2.job_id
            FROM staffschedules s2 
            WHERE s2.store_id=store_id                  
            AND ((s2.start_date BETWEEN TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')) AND TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))+(1-1/24/60/60)
               AND TO_CHAR(s2.start_date,'HH24:MI') <= s2.start_time)
               OR((s2.end_date BETWEEN TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))+1/24/60/60 AND TRUNC(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))+1)
               AND TO_CHAR(s2.end_date,'HH24:MI') >= s2.end_time))
            AND SUBSTR(ses2.org_path,INSTR(ses2.org_path,'/',1,7)+1,8) = 'NOTALLOCATED')
```

which can be changed to just

```
            AND SUBSTR(ses2.org_path,INSTR(ses2.org_path,'/',1,7)+1,8) <> 'NOTALLOCATED')
```

without subqueries and `NOT IN`.
If you need to join another tables to perform a test, better to do it in main select: do outer join and then test field:

```
select * from (
  select
    ss.*,
    nvl(SUBSTR(ses2.org_path,INSTR(ses2.org_path,'/',1,7)+1,12),'X') alloc_flag
  from
    staffschedules ss,
    some_table     ses2
  where
    ses2.some_field (+) = ss.some_field and ...
)
where alloc_flag <> 'NOTALLOCATED'
```

Another good example of such situation is this condition:

```
AND job_id NOT IN (
  Select job_Id 
  From staffStatus 
  Where Trunc(job_Date)=Trunc(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')) And Store_Id!='15'
)
```

It contains two bad things. One of them discussed above, and next is usage of `!=` in condition. Such conditions eliminates any possibility of effective index usage. And worst thing with this case is that all of your indexes have a `store_id` on first place, so database engine must loop through entire index to find all conditions and can't fallback to another index with `job_date` on first place.
So, that condition can be rewrited with same technique

```
select * from (
  select
    ss.*,
    nvl(statuses.store_id,'X') status_store_id
  from
    staffschedules ss,
    staffstatus    statuses
  where
    statuses.job_id (+) = ss.some_field 
    Trunc(job_Date (+)) = Trunc(to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY'))
    and ...
)
where status_store_id = '15'
```

And last thing is function usage on fields while joining. `Trunc(job_date)` looks  intuitive may be, but bad for performance because database can't use index on `job_date` in that case. So in such situation better to use boundary conditions:

```
    job_Date >= to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')
    and 
    job_Date < to_date('07/08/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') + 1
```

And last, I written example query wich gets full schedule list. You can test it on [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c7f0/3) or look below.
It returns full set of schedules and statuses for specified store and date.
Because I not sure about understanding scheduling logic, you can filter a results of the query on your own.

```
with params as (
  -- Just to write parameters only once.
  -- Note that parameter date truncated.
  select   
    trunc(to_date('07/24/2013 07:20','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')) as date_val,
    '15'                                                    as store_id
  from dual
), 
store_jobs_from_schedule as ( 
  -- Select all valid schedules on desired date for specified store with corresponding statuses if any.
  select                        
    scheduled_jobs.job_id            job_id, 
    scheduled_jobs.store_id          schedule_store_id, 
    scheduled_jobs.start_date        schedule_start_date, 
    scheduled_jobs.start_date_time   schedule_start_time,
    scheduled_jobs.end_date          schedule_end_date, 
    scheduled_jobs.end_date_time     schedule_end_time,
    scheduled_jobs.jobname           schedule_job_name,
    status_list.job_seq_id           status_id,       
    status_list.store_id             status_store_id,
    status_list.job_date             status_job_date,
    status_list.status               status
  from 
    (                         
      select  -- get all schedules for specified date and store.
        p.date_val,
        schedules.job_id,
        schedules.store_id,  
        schedules.start_date,
        ( -- Calculate exact start time as date and time value
          trunc(schedules.start_date) +  
          (to_date(schedules.start_time,'hh24:mi') - to_date('00:00','hh24:mi'))
        ) start_date_time,
        schedules.end_date,
        ( -- Calculate exact end time as date and time value
          trunc(schedules.end_date) +  
          (to_date(schedules.end_time,'hh24:mi') - to_date('00:00','hh24:mi'))
        ) end_date_time,
        schedules.jobname
      from 
        params         p,
        staffschedules schedules
      where                                   
        -- scheduled to specified store
        schedules.store_id = p.store_id
        and                                    
        -- start before the end of desired date
        schedules.start_date < p.date_val + 1  
        and                               
        -- end after beginning of desired date
        schedules.end_date >= p.date_val  
    ) 
                scheduled_jobs,
    staffstatus status_list
  where                                                           
    -- Check if schedule start time are valid
    (scheduled_jobs.start_date <= scheduled_jobs.start_date_time) 
    and
    -- Check if schedule end time are valid
    (scheduled_jobs.end_date >= scheduled_jobs.end_date_time)
    and                          
    -- Link status by staff and date if any - only on desired date, 
    -- not for full schedule length
    status_list.job_id (+) = scheduled_jobs.job_id
    and
    status_list.job_date (+) >= scheduled_jobs.date_val
    and
    status_list.job_date (+) < scheduled_jobs.date_val + 1
),
store_stuff_jobs as (
  -- Select all statuses for specified date and store and link it to corresponding schedules if any
  select -- clear data in invalid schedules 
    job_id                                                                   job_id,    
    decode(is_valid_schedule,'N', null,               schedule_store_id)   schedule_store_id, 
    decode(is_valid_schedule,'N', cast(null as date), schedule_start_date) schedule_start_date,
    decode(is_valid_schedule,'N', cast(null as date), schedule_start_time) schedule_start_time,
    decode(is_valid_schedule,'N', cast(null as date), schedule_end_date)   schedule_end_date,
    decode(is_valid_schedule,'N', cast(null as date), schedule_end_time)   schedule_end_time,
    decode(is_valid_schedule,'N', null,               schedule_job_name)   schedule_job_name,
    status_id                                                                status_id,       
    status_store_id                                                          status_store_id,
    status_job_date                                                          status_job_date,
    status                                                                   status
  from (  
    select -- Calculate if selected schedule are valid             
      job_id, 
      schedule_store_id, 
      schedule_start_date, 
      schedule_start_time,
      schedule_end_date, 
      schedule_end_time,
      schedule_job_name,
      status_id,       
      status_store_id,
      status_job_date,
      status,
      ( -- Calculate flag to check if times of schedules are valid 
        case
          when  
            (schedule_start_date > schedule_start_time)
            or
            (schedule_end_date < schedule_end_time)
          then 'N'
          else 'Y'
        end        
      )   is_valid_schedule
    from (
      select
        status_list.job_id          job_id, 
        schedules.store_id          schedule_store_id, 
        schedules.start_date        schedule_start_date, 
        ( -- Calculate exact start time as date and time value
          trunc(schedules.start_date) +  
          (to_date(schedules.start_time,'hh24:mi') - to_date('00:00','hh24:mi'))
        )                           schedule_start_time,
        schedules.end_date          schedule_end_date, 
        ( -- Calculate exact end time as date and time value
          trunc(schedules.end_date) +  
          (to_date(schedules.end_time,'hh24:mi') - to_date('00:00','hh24:mi'))
        )                           schedule_end_time,
        schedules.jobname           schedule_job_name,
        status_list.job_seq_id      status_id,       
        status_list.store_id        status_store_id,
        status_list.job_date        status_job_date,
        status_list.status          status
      from
        params         p, 
        staffstatus    status_list,
        staffschedules schedules
      where
        status_list.job_date >= p.date_val     
        and
        status_list.job_date < p.date_val + 1    
        and
        status_list.store_id = p.store_id
        and                                    
        -- Link schedules for same staff on same date if any. 
        -- Even schedules to same store, because we need exactly same  
        -- record as in first query to eliminate duplicates on last step.
        schedules.job_id (+) = status_list.job_id
        and
        schedules.start_date (+) < trunc(status_list.job_date) + 1  -- start before the end of desired date
        and
        schedules.end_date (+) >= trunc(status_list.job_date)  -- end after beginning of desired date
    )
  )  
)
  select  
    -- records comes from schedules
    job_id, 
    schedule_store_id store_id, 
    schedule_store_id, 
    schedule_start_date, 
    schedule_start_time,
    schedule_end_date, 
    schedule_end_time,
    schedule_job_name,
    status_id,       
    status_store_id,
    status_job_date,
    status
  from 
    store_jobs_from_schedule
union -- duplicates eliminated
  select  
    -- records comes from status
    job_id, 
    status_store_id store_id,
    schedule_store_id, 
    schedule_start_date, 
    schedule_start_time,
    schedule_end_date, 
    schedule_end_time,
    schedule_job_name,
    status_id,       
    status_store_id,
    status_job_date,
    status
  from 
    store_stuff_jobs
order by 
  job_id, schedule_start_date, schedule_start_time
```

Comment: Thanks ThinkJet. This works fine. But it won't return the schedule for this scenario. Employee xyz's home store is 13. today he is working in store 12. In staffstatus table, xyz store is 12 (host store, so attendance is marked in store 12) and staffschedules table xyz store is 13( schedules always with home store id). The outer where condition reject the schedules with store id 13 if I want to fetch store 12 schedules. Is there any to fetch different stores schedules using this query?

Comment: @user2556379 You changed schema significantly compared to first version of the question. What field corresponds to `staffid` from previous question? Why you split date and time into 2 separate columns? Why time stored in character format? What is the purpose to comparasions like `TO_CHAR(start_date,'HH24:MI') <= start_time)` from same row?

Comment: Sorry for the change. Staffid is replaced by Job_Id. Sample data in the staffschedules.

Comment: storeid  job_id startdate starttime enddate endtime jobname

Comment: I updated the sample data for staffschedules table. please have a look. I need to check the inner shift start time and endtime is inline with shifts start time and end time. for this I put TO_CHAR(start_date,'HH24:MI') <= start_time) condition

Comment: @user2556379 Sorry for long inactivity interval. I was too busy on my work last week and don't have even a one hour to review changes and my answer. Hope that I  have a chance to update my answer tomorrow.

Comment: If you have time on week ends, Please give me some ideas

Answer (score 0):

Your main filter is on `date`. So you will want to index by date. But this will only make sense if the number of records for a date is significantly less than the number of records in the table. Say < 5%.  So your first best bang for your buck would be an index on `staffschedules.date` (or some other multi-part index starting with date).

You should run the two queries individually with an example date in sqlplus and see where the time is being spent. If the time is being spent on the first query, then this will be the `date` index or even a `date-store` index. This part should not be slow.

If the second part of the UNION is slow, break that into two parts and investigate each:

```
SELECT *
  FROM staffschedules
  WHERE date = v_date
    AND store <> v_store
```

and

```
SELECT staffid
  FROM staffstatus
  WHERE store=v_store
    AND jobdate=v_date
```

If the first part is slow, again, the date index. If the second one is slow, then it may need an index on `staffstatus.jobdate`. If each runs fairly quickly, then you have to look at how the `staffid` is joined, but it is most likely a case of an index on `jobdate`.

Comment: Second part of the UNION is taking time. I updated with Explain plan and table schema. Please have a look. As per my understanding, second part is executed like selection in staff schedules, selection in staffstatus and then tables are joined. So it takes time. Is there any way that first join and then selection. I mean join the rows and then select in staffschedules?